# how can a registered member only can access my company website from android phone

Tags: java, android, url

i want my company website to access from my android phone but that website can only be accessed by registered member

i have login page in that i have to enter registered email and passwrd than directly from the login page only i have to redirect to my company web url ???

Please give suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, to be more explicit :

How to secure and restrict access to a website ?

**Restrict network access**

Maybe the simpliest solution. A web site is not always available on the internet or for everybody. In fact if your website sit in some machine in your company office, make it available on the net require more effort than just let local computers access to it.

What does that mean ? You configure your firewall and your network to allow access of your server for only some IP address/port. To continue on this network only solution, you can create a VPN that include your mobile phone devices.

**Include authentification and authorization management directly in the application**

The first solution is a first pass. It allow you to forbidd access to most people out of your organisation. But maybe you want more, you want for exemple that only people from marketing do have access to the web site. Or maybe you want depending of the user (or user group), allow them to do differents things.

The best way to do that is to directly manage uses rights into your website. You authenticate users, and when a specific functionnality is requested your firt verify is user has credential.

If you already have an IT department, it is likely that a directory is available with all users, their password and their groups. You can base your check on the directory, avoiding the harsle to create/delete users in your application directly.

**Using a proxy to secure or authenticate access**

This solution is like a melt of the other ones. First you make sure sure using network restriction that your web site is only accessible using the proxy machine (so only one IP basically). Then you use a web server (like Apache HTTPD server) as a proxy, or a gateway to access the website.

Basically, when a user want to request your website, it doesn't directly ask the application that manage it, but the proxy. Because the application server is isolated in the network, it doesn't have to be secured.

The proxy allow you to fine tune the behaviour of your web site :

- you can add encryption using SSL to
  all data that transit from the client
  to server, so no senssible data is
  sent unprotected
- you can compress all    data that
  transit to optimize the    bandwidth
  usage (really important for    mobile
  device and their not so good
  internet connexion).
- you can use HTTP authentification to 
  check user has    the right to access
  to the page. This    can be just a
  login/password check,    or a client
  certificate to fully    secure the
  connexion, allowing only    device
  with the certificate to be    granted
  access.

You can tune access per group to certain part of the site, but this is not as flexible as retrictions done directly by the web site application.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't catch you very well. Do you mean that you want your company website can just be accessed by android phone for registered member? If so, I think you can check what browser type can be used in android phone, and in your website check it from http request, like "String browserType=(String)request.getHeader("User-Agent");" .

Comment: Checking the navigator type would make it don't work if the user choose an alternate navigator on it's phone (yes firefox do exist too in Android for exemple), it would also not prevent it from being accessed from other devices (it is easy to tell your browser to send another user agent or to use an intermediate proxy that will do it for you)